# Hide element when keyboard is shown

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard

I want to hide my button when keyboard is shown and and move it back when User closes keyboard. It works but I've noticed really annyoing effect of jumping button, really ugly 0.0001 animation. I think that the problem exsists because my code hides element right after my component rerenders. Could you help me to avoid this type of "jumping"?

```
const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = React.useState();

useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', function() {
        setKeyboardVisible(false);
    });
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', function() {
        setKeyboardVisible(true);
    });
});

{isKeyboardVisible && (
    <Button
    style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    borderRadius: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    width: '100%',}}
    title="Delete"
       }}
   />
)}
```

Comment: Are you testing it on iOS? Using `keyboardWillShow` and `keyboardWillHide` tends to work better for iOS

Comment: On iOS it works fine, it looks bad only on Android.